# Finding probability function (simple problem)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following problem with solution, but I do not understand the solution. I will appreciate your help.

**Problem**: In class there are 10 pupils: 3 girls and 7 boys. Every morning the teacher randomly allocates the pupils to pairs. What is probability function X for the number of mixed (boy + girl) couples?

**Solution**:

[Stage 1] Number of mixed pairs can be either 3 or 1.

[Stage 2] For calculating probability we need to check the gender of the partner of each one of the girls.

[Stage 3] {X=3} will happen if for each girl will be a boy as partner.   $P(X=3)=\dfrac79 \times\dfrac67 \times 1 = \dfrac23$

[Stage 4] {X=1} might happen in two ways: a) the partner of girl No 1 is boy (7 possibilities) and partner of girl No 2 is also girl (1 possibility); b)  the partner of girl No 1 is girl (2 possibilities) and for remaining girl we have a boy (no choice).  $P(X=1) = \dfrac79 \times \dfrac17 + \dfrac29 \times 1 = \dfrac13$

**What do I miss**: In [stage 3] we check for partner for the first girl, then for the second and third. But where are the permutations of girls? For the pairing with $\dfrac79$ it can be any of three girls. Where is it taken into account? The same for [stage 4]: to start they talk about girl No 1, but it could be also girl No 2 or 3. Where is it taken into account?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format questions. It makes them easier to read and easier to search for.

Comment: Can you please edit in my post one fraction as an example? I tried \frac ab and it is not shows up formatted.

Comment: Try \$ \frac{a}{b} $. The dollar signs enclosing your code are important.

Answer (score 2):

As another approach, you could note that the chances of Alice and Betty being paired is $1/9$, since each of the 9 other students has an equal chance of being Alice's partner. Similarly for Alice and Cathy, and also for Betty and Cathy. Since these three events are pairwise exclusive, the probability of one of them happening is just their sum $1/9 + 1/9 + 1/9 = 1/3$, and the complement (all three women paired with men) has probability $1-1/3=2/3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ned! Your solution is probably most elegant! Can you please take a look at my remark to David K (below). Maybe you can resolve my confusion?

Comment: I like this answer too. It is fundamentally different from the solution in the question, and it does use the symmetry of the permutations. We have three cases instead of six (the full number of permutations) because we don't distinguish between the ways the children in a pair could be listed in sequence. That is, we don't distinguish the pair (Alice, Betty) from the pair (Betty, Alice).

Answer (score 0):

You could include permutations, but then you also have to multiply with the probability on that permutation. For stage 3, you get
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{7}{9}\frac{6}{7}1\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{7}{9}\frac{6}{7}1\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{7}{9}\frac{6}{7}1\right) = \frac{7}{9}\frac{6}{7}.$$
This is different from when you are counting cases.

Comment: Thanks. The last one you mention is my problem. How I differentiate between the problems that require counting (and taking all scenarios) vs. those that use probabilities (and do not take all scenarios)?

Comment: @John both methods work, try solve it via counting too!

Comment: Yes, I know the solution via counting. But I do not catch the principle. Can any problem be solved using both probabilities and counting?  Maybe you can give me the link that explains the distinction. Thanks a lot

Comment: @John Counting only works if each outcome is equally likely. Otherwise you just pick the method that is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_1$ be the event that girl number 1 is paired with a boy,
$B_2$ be the event that girl number 2 is paired with a boy,
$B_3$ be the event that girl number 3 is paired with a boy.
Then
$$
P(X = 3) = P(B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3). \tag1
$$
Is there any doubt about Equation $(1)$? On the left we have the probability of an event $X = 3,$ which says there are three boy-girl pairings.
On the right we have an event $B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3,$ which says that each girl is paired with a boy.

Is it possible for $B_1,$ $B_2,$ and $B_3$ all to be true and yet $X \neq 3$?
Is it possible that $X = 3$ and yet there is any one or more of the events $B_1,$ $B_2,$ and $B_3$ that does not occur?
No, we have three girl-boy pairings if and only if each girl is paired with a boy. The two events are identical, and they have the same probability.

Next we may observe that
$$
P(B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3) 
 = P(B_1) \, P(B_2 \mid B_1) \, P(B_3 \mid B_1 \cap B_2). \tag2
$$
Equation $(2)$ is a universal equation about conditional probability.
It is true for any three events in any probability space, provided that
all four of the probabilities in the equation are defined.

Now observe that
\begin{align}
P(B_1) &= \frac79, \\
P(B_2 \mid B_1) &= \frac67, \\
P(B_3 \mid B_1 \cap B_2) &= 1.
\end{align}

Note that even though each girl is distinctly identified, so that permutations of them are distinguishable, the formulas are all still true.
In fact these formulas do not even make sense unless you identify each girl distinctly from the others.

Now, if you like, you can permute the girls within the formulas.
For example, we have
$$
P(B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3) 
 = P(B_2) \, P(B_3 \mid B_2) \, P(B_1 \mid B_2 \cap B_3).
$$
But this is not a separate *case* from Equation $(2)$; both equations are describing the exact same event, $B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3.$
Even if you permute the girls within that event's description,
for example if you write $B_2 \cap B_3 \cap B_1$ it is still the same event, not a new event to be counted.

Comment: Thank you, David! But your last remark is exactly what confuses me. If I a girl is distinctly identified (i.e., B1 is the event for specific girl),  how it comes up that the solution is generic and I do not need any permutations to account for different girls (e.g..,  B1 be the event that girl number 2 is paired with a boy). For example, in solution of Ned (see above), I still need iterate over all such possibilities.

Comment: In my solution, the probabilities are NOT conditional, whereas they are here. The overall problem has a symmetry amongst the 3 women (i.e. the intersection) but the formula used in computing it does not have to reflect that symmetry, and the conditional probabilities make it work. As a simpler example let Joe and Fred each pick a ball from {2 red, 2 blue} without replacement. Prob that both pick R is (1/2)(1/3)= 1/6 and it doesn't matter who picked the first ball or even if they reached in and grabbed them simultaneously. But ... $P(J=R)=P(F=R)=1/2$

Comment: @Ned My answer is based on the solution given in the question, whereas yours is a fundamentally different approach which (I agree) does not use conditional probabilities.

Comment: To Ned: I see, thanks a lot! A rule of thumb for me is as soon as I deal with conditional probabilities (i.e., an experiment is done in several stages without replacement) I should not care about the symmetry because it is built-in  within calculation. Right?  In fact, I think it works this way regardless of whether it is conditional (i.e., without replacements)  or not. For example, if in your example, had it been a replacement, I would have received 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4 - again no need to account for symmetry.

Comment: In a sense, this answer _does_ have a permutation of the girls, in the sense that we choose one girl to put in the unconditional probability $P(B_i)$, then a second one to condition on the first, then condition the third on the other two. But each such permutation gives us a complete answer that agrees (by symmetry) with the answer we would get by any other permutation.